# Как сделать перенаправление всех запросов на другой сервер (анонимайзер)?

Tags: php, curl, telegram-bot, telegram

В общем что мне нужно, в связи с блокировкой Telegram я не могу использовать своего бота, так как не могу использовать на своём локальном сервере прокси, так как меняется IP, у меня есть домен, и есть привязка этого домена к статическому IP. Если я подцеплю прокси, я во первых потеряю скорость а во вторых у меня отвалится мой основной домен, где лежит скрипт бота. Так вот, как мне сделать скрипт, точнее как его написать, чтобы все полностью POST, GET, и так далее запросы перенаправлялись на другой сервер?

То есть, сервер telegram (post/get и тд) -> сервер находящийся не в РФ(принял любой post/get и тд, и отправил на мой сервер) -> мой сервер в РФ (принял post/get и тд, отправил ответ на промежуточный сервер).
И обратно, мой сервер (принял любой post/get, отправил ответ post/get) -> сервер находящийся не в РФ (принял любой post/get, перенаправил любой post/get и тд на мой сервер) -> сервер telegram (получил post/get и тд, отправил на промежуточный сервер, а промежуточный отправил на мой локальный).

Получается типа анонимайзер, хотя нет, получается анонимайзер, но я что-то не могу догнать, а как это будет вообще выглядеть? Это надо сделать конструктор или что? Помогите, ткните носом, напишите мануал если не сложно =)

Вот только не надо мне предлагать использовать для этих целей тупо сервер не в рф, меня это не прикалывает. У меня всё цивильно через самбу и /root расшарено по локалке. Что хочу то и ворочу. Спасибо за понимание.

Вот в картинке что я хочу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня такой конфиг:
Домен (настроены A-записи на статический IP).
Роутер (открыты порты и сделано перенаправление на сервер).
Сервер (Ubuntu + Apache).

Почему я именно так захотел? Я не горю жланием покупать VPS хостинг, чтобы ставить на него библиотеки которые будут удовлетворять мои потребности. Я не могу расширить функционал на VPS ровно так как мне надо, так как нет рута.

Comment: `Если я подцеплю прокси ...`. Вы в курсе, что 1) можно развернуть локальный прокси на nginx и повесить на отдельный порт прокси для конкретного IP адреса, и бросать дальше соединение на сервер "не РФ"? 2) прокси можно задать не глобально, а в текущем окружении? например, одно консольное окно с прокси (выставлена переменная окружения `set http_proxy`), другое - без. А вообще, уточните как это сейчас работает - готовая библиотека с веб-сокетами, тупой curl (`CURLOPT_PROXY`), или еще что-то? @see https://habrahabr.ru/post/133703/

Comment: @TotalPusher, окей, я добавил прокси, как тогда это будет выглядеть? Я через проксю смогу передать данные на сервак телеги, а сервер телеги попытается отправить ответ на мой домен, скрипту на домене. И не сможет этого сделать, так как мой провайдер заблочил сервера телеги, и я просто тупо не смогу получить данные так как закрыто либо соединение.

Comment: Я не знаю, как работает у вас. У меня бот на NodeJS, там сразу идут веб-сокеты. А это значит, что соединение постоянное, и оно создается с моей стороны, значит маршрут уже есть. Как сделано у вас?

Comment: @TotalPusher, у меня вот как: локальный сервер на Ubuntu с Apache, на нём развёрнуто много сайтов с поддоменами, на одном поддомене у меня как раз таки бот с телеграм сдк скачанного и установленного через компосер. Далее у провайдера я установил статику, открыл порты в роутере и сделал перенаправления, вот, вроде всё...

Comment: надо смотреть сорцы. напишите ссылку на пакет, который используете.

Comment: @TotalPusher git: irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76162/discussion-between-mrmex-and-total-pusher).

Comment: посмотрите файл `vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php`, метод `create`, в него возможно передать прокси через `$options['proxy']`. Как это прокинуть из telegram-bot-sdk, я не смог разобраться без запуска скрипта. Поставьте в начало этого метода `die(var_dump(debug_backtrace(2)))` и посмотрите стек вызовов. Возможно, это тот же самый массив, что в Api.php `sendMessage(array $params)`. Я обсуждаю тут, и надеюсь, что в конце мы дойдем до решения, которое оформим в виде ответа на изначальный вопрос.

Comment: PS. Телеграмм сам стучится на сервер, если стоит [веб-хук](https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#setwebhook). Он не обязателен. Библиотека, я думаю, сама проверяет наличие новых сообщений. @see `Api::setWebhook()` `Api::getWebhookUpdate()`

Comment: @TotalPusher, нет, сам сервер телеги посылает запрос вебхуку, в следствии чего обрабатывается код, и выдаётся результат в JSON'не. А что если написать скрипт с роутером и имитацией полной действий как на сервере телеграма? То есть пост запрос редиректить? Только надо этот пост запрос сначала записать, а потом отправить уже мне на сервер...

Comment: @TotalPusher https://git.dev.hsdn.org/pub/mcacher вот что нашёл, решение по ходу всех моих проблем, только один вопрос, как решить проблему с ошибкой 400 или ошибками на то что происходит редирект с http на https, либо вообще ничего не выдаёт. Я для примера вписал данный сайт и получил ни одного символа с сервера...

Comment: И нужно ли мне поднимать сервер сокетов? Так написано в мануале. Нет, я не хочу делать на сервере на своём это, мне нужно хотя бы сделать пробный тест этого дела

Comment: `нет, сам сервер телеги посылает запрос вебхуку` - пропишите адрес хуку "сервер не РФ". домен третьего уровня завести для вас не должно быть проблемой. а там с помощью nginx проксируйте себе, могу скинуть конфиг для этого. `mcacher` - как меня прикалывают коленочные решения на PHP. "я знаю PHP, а давайте я напишу свой прокси на нем!". Правильное решение: нормальный прокси не-на-PHP. Кстати, где-то прописывается адрес телеги? Его тоже можно на свой прокси заменить. Может сделаем по-быстрому прокси в "не-РФ", я покажу как это работает?

Comment: @TotalPusher, значит план такой, я беру бесплатный хостинг, там размещаю скрипт прокси, после этого, я регаю на том же хостинге бесплатный домен, меняю в конфиге SDK телеги основной адрес сервера на другой, далее... ngingx, у меня сервер с апачем, или это на новоиспечённом сервере посреднике? А сервер меняется в файле TelegramClient.php:19. И если сделать прокси, он не будет затрагивать другие сайты?

Comment: почти да. на своем сайте нужно поменять сервер телеги на свой прокси, остальные работы - на прокси-сервере. но "скрипт прокси" нужно заменить на "прокси-сервер", можно использовать для этого nginx. домен третьего уровня можно взять от основного сайта. например, proxy.site.ru, для этого нужно просто добавить A-запись с IP прокси-сервера в DNS. Мы тут не будем проксировать весь трафик, а тупо поменяем путь для одного конкретного домена

Comment: @TotalPusher, блин, у меня апач на сервере.